# Keyframe not Scrolling in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, keyframe

First time using keyframes so I may be missing something obvious, but for some reason I can't get this to scroll with Chrome. It works fine on IE and Firefox. The only solution I found on here involved an added semi-colon which Firefox ignored but Chrome did not. Any help would be great.

```
.example3 {
height: 1920px; 
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
font-family: "Flama";
font-size: 35px; 
}

example3 h3 {
position: absolute;
width: 1080px;
height: 1920px;
margin: 0;
line-height: 50px;
**-webkit-**animation: example3 20s linear infinite;  /* Apply the animation */
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes example3 {
from {top: 1920px;}
    to {top: -2920px;}
} 

/* Standard syntax */ 
@keyframes example3 {
    from {top: 1920px;}
    to {top: -2920px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Forgot "-webkit-" before animation!